# Canvas. Отследить нажатие мыши по грани полигона

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Имеется следующий код на React

```
const [dots, setDots] = useState<any>({
    zone: {
        coords: [],
    },
})
    
const drawPoly = (poly: any, color: string) => {
    contextRef.current!.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,100,100,0)'
    contextRef.current!.lineWidth = 1
    contextRef.current!.strokeStyle = color

    contextRef.current?.beginPath()
    contextRef.current?.moveTo(poly[0][0], poly[0][1])

    for (let i = 1; i < poly.length; i++) {
        contextRef.current?.lineTo(poly[i][0], poly[i][1])
    }

    contextRef.current?.closePath()
    contextRef.current?.fill()
    contextRef.current?.stroke()
}

const drawPoint = (coords: any, color: string) => {
    contextRef.current!.lineJoin = 'round'
    contextRef.current!.lineWidth = 5
    contextRef.current!.strokeStyle = color
    for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        contextRef.current!.beginPath()
        contextRef.current!.arc(
            coords[i][0],
            coords[i][1],
            3,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI,
            false
        )
        contextRef.current!.fillStyle = color
        contextRef.current!.fill()
        contextRef.current!.lineWidth = 5
        contextRef.current!.stroke()
    }
}

const setPoint = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>): void => {
    const bounding = canvasRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect()

        setDots((prev: any) => ({
            ...prev,
            coords: [
                ...prev.coords,
                    [
                        e.clientX - bounding!.left,
                        e.clientY - bounding!.top,
                    ],
        }))
}

const drawPolygons = () => {
    for (let key in dots) {
        if (dots[key].coords.length) {
            drawPoint(dots[key].coords, '#fff')
            drawPoly(dots[key].coords, '#fff')
        }
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    if (dots[key].coords.length) {
        drawPolygons()
    }
}, [dots, drawPolygons])
return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} onClick={setPoint}></canvas>
)
```

Я приложил его в сокращенном варианте, при необходимости дополню. Суть компонента: при нажатии на canvas, вызывается функция setPoint, которая записывает координаты в стейт dots. При изменении dots вызывается функция drawPolygons, которая отрисовывает полигон, циклично вызывая функции drawPoly и drawPoint. В результате получается полигон, отрисованный по поставленным нами точкам.

Проблема: мне нужно отследить нажатие именно по грани отрисованного полигона и получить точки, между которыми проведена линия. Я пробовал добавить функцию, которая будет проверять принадлежность поставленной точки к полигону, но это совсем не то, что мне нужно. Есть ли какие-то способы проверить, нажали ли мы конкретно на грань полигона или нет?

Comment: Не грань, но ребро многоугольника вещь бесконечно тонкая, попасть в неё сложно. Как вы хотите решить тонкую трудность с толщиной отрезков?

Comment: Есть книга https://riptutorial.com/Download/html5-canvas-ru.pdf там есть раздел глава 6: Навигация по пути, возможно это расширит варианты твоих решений.